# Does someone know how to make this type of program in java generics?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; 
  
public class ComputeElectricityBill { 
  
    // Function to calculate the 
    // electricity bill 
    public static int calculateBill(int units) 
    { 
  
        // Condition to find the charges 
        // bar in which the units consumed 
        // is fall 
        if (units <= 100) { 
            return units * 10; 
        } 
        else if (units <= 200) { 
            return (100 * 10) 
                + (units - 100) 
                      * 15; 
        } 
        else if (units <= 300) { 
            return (100 * 10) 
                + (100 * 15) 
                + (units - 200) 
                      * 20; 
        } 
        else if (units > 300) { 
            return (100 * 10) 
                + (100 * 15) 
                + (100 * 20) 
                + (units - 300) 
                      * 25; 
        } 
        return 0; 
    } 
  
    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int units = 250; 
  
        System.out.println( 
            calculateBill(units)); 
    } 
}
```

How to convert this into generic way? I studied generics but can't figure out a way to make something like this in generic way

Comment: Why have you decided to move to generic? Did you try this task by yourself?

Comment: I don't think this is suitable for generics. I suggest you read a tutorial about what generics do. You can also look at examples of generics such as the Collections API. Using collections in your code is a great way to learn about what kinds of problems generics can solve.

Comment: Generics is used when you have the same code for different (typically bounded) types.  But you don't have different types in your code, or any types in fact.

Comment: You may misunderstood the usage of generics.